# Click on a element and get a previously elements text in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='nrOfCopies'>2</div>
<button class='itemRemove'>Remove</button>
```

```js
$(document).on('click','.itemRemove', function(){
    var num = $(this).closest('.nrOfCopies').text();
    console.log('number = ' + num);
});
```

The result from the console.log is "number = " (a empty line) way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest()` is used to retreive parent elements, `.nrOfCopies` is a sibling so try `prev()`:

```
var num = $(this).prev('.nrOfCopies').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

`.closest()` finds parent nodes. You want `prev()`:

```js
$(document).on('click','.itemRemove', function(){
    var num = $(this).prev('.nrOfCopies').text();
    console.log('number = ' + num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='nrOfCopies'>2</div>
<button class='itemRemove'>Remove</button>
```